# Replace For Loop That References Preceding Row (index - 1). .shift() Not Applicable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a For Loop that performs a conditional test on a value in the currently indexed row, as well as a value from the preceding row (index minus one). It is painfully slow and I would like to make it more pythonic but have been unable to find a good, fast solution.

I started looking at .apply(), .rolling.apply() and itterrows() but none of those seem to allow reference to both the current and previous rows within a custom function.

Solutions I've come accross in my search often involve using .shift() to create a new column containing the data from the previous row. However, the values I want to use are set as the loop progresses, so doing a shift() prior will not work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True,True,False,False,True,False],
              'State': [1,0,0,0,0,0]}) 

for i in range(1,len(df)):

    if df['State'].iloc[i-1] == 1:
        if df['A'].iloc[i] == True:
            df['State'].iloc[i] = 3
        else:
            df['State'].iloc[i] = 1

    elif df['State'].iloc[i-1] == 2:
        if df['A'].iloc[i] == True:
            df['State'].iloc[i] = 3
        else:
            df['State'].iloc[i] = 2

    else: #df.['State'] == 3
        if df['A'].iloc[i] == True:
            df['State'].iloc[i] = 1
        else:
            df['State'].iloc[i] = 3
```

The For Loop above executes as expected, but it is painfully slow. This is a minimal example, the data I am processing is more complex and comprised of many thousands of rows.

I'm used to working in C derived languages and could use some tips to improve my Python.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can escape using a for loop for such updates using pandas.  Hopefully I will be proved wrong

Comment: I suggest to classify these conditions, and combine mask. for example `mask1 = df['State'].shift(1)==1` and then use `df.loc[combinedMask, 'State''] = value` to assign new value to State.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding this response. Masking only serves as a method to simplify or rearrange the logic here. Using .shift(1) does not seem useful because it presupposes the dataframe is already completely determined. The 'State' column is determined row by row, relying on the calculation in the previous row, so .shift(1) does not work because the 'State' of each row is not determined when .shift(1) is applied.